# Generate values between two numbers and flatten the table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SnowflakeDB and have the following table

```
Key  Seats
 a    7,7
 b    6,8
```

I would like to flatten it and at the same time generate seats between the two numbers. I got the flatten part, but cannot figure out how to generate seats between the two provided numbers.

```
select a.*, b.val from mytable a, lateral flatten(input=> split(Seats,','))
```

The query above will generate the table below.

```
Key  Seats
 a     7
 a     7
 b     6
 b     8
```

There is a seven missing for the b seats. I would like the final result to be

```
Key  Seats
 a     7
 a     7
 b     6
 b     7
 b     8
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to add a JavaScript function that creates an array with a dense sequence for your input, before flattening.

For example:

```
create or replace table mytable(key varchar, seats varchar) as
select * from values
    ('a', '7,7'), 
    ('b', '6,9');

create or replace function fillme(STR varchar)
returns variant
language javascript
as '
let start = 1 * STR.split(",")[0];
let end = 1 * STR.split(",")[1];
let res = [];
for (let s = start; s <= end; s++) {
  res.push(s);
}
return res;
'
;
/
select key, seats, fillme(seats) from mytable;
select a.*, b.value from mytable a, lateral flatten(input=> fillme(Seats)) b;
```

The output for the last 2 queries is:

```
select key, seats, fillme(seats) from mytable;
-----+-------+---------------+
 KEY | SEATS | FILLME(SEATS) |
-----+-------+---------------+
 a   | 7,7   | [             |
     |       |   7           |
     |       | ]             |
 b   | 6,9   | [             |
     |       |   6,          |
     |       |   7,          |
     |       |   8,          |
     |       |   9           |
     |       | ]             |
-----+-------+---------------+
2 rows in result (first row: 421 msec; total: 423 msec)
select a.*, b.value from mytable a, lateral flatten(input=> fillme(Seats)) b;
-----+-------+-------+
 KEY | SEATS | VALUE |
-----+-------+-------+
 a   | 7,7   | 7     |
 b   | 6,9   | 6     |
 b   | 6,9   | 7     |
 b   | 6,9   | 8     |
 b   | 6,9   | 9     |
-----+-------+-------+
```

Assuming you don't have millions of seats, this should be enough.

Comment: Works great. Thanks.